# Ejecución de sentencias dentro de ciclo For en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy realizando una validación simple de una lista, para saber si cierto elemento se encuentra ya en los valores de la lista. El código es así:

```
elem1 = 5
myList = [1, 5, 6]

for x in myList:
    print("\nElemento de lista: " + str(x))
    if myList[x] == elem1:
        print("El valor es igual\nValor en lista: " + str(myList[x])+"\nelem1: " + str(elem1))
```

1. Mi primer inconveniente se da cuando se encuentra una coincidencia, porque la salida del código muestra primero la ejecución de la sentencia `if` y luego imprime el elemento de lista.
2. Luego obtengo un error que me indica que el siguiente índice de la lista está fuera de rango: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Entonces, la salida de mi código se genera algo así:

```
Elemento de lista: 1 

El valor es igual
Valor en lista: 5
elem1: 5
Elemento de lista: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\dirección\del\archivo\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    if myList[x] == elem1:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

No entiendo, pues parece que estuviese saltando a un índice mayor sin que se esté indicando eso...  Sin embargo, si decido llamar un `print(myList)` o utilizar un

```
for x in myList:
    print(x)
```

la lista se imprime normal.

Agradecería que alguien me pueda explicar qué exactamente hace que mi código genere esta salida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que `x` representa el elemento del array, no el índice del mismo. Por lo tanto si haces `myList[x]` vas a obtener un error cuando sea 5 (el segundo elemento).

El motivo por el cuál en la primera iteración imprime "Es igual" está también relacionado a esto porque `myList[x]` en la primera iteración es `myList[1]` lo cuál arroja 5 que es el segundo elemento de tu array (recuerda que los arrays tienen indexación que inicia en 0).

Corrigiendo esto tu código funciona correctamente:

```
elem1 = 5
myList = [1, 5, 6]

for x in myList:
    print("\nElemento de lista: " + str(x))
    if x == elem1:
        print("El valor es igual\nValor en lista: " + str(x)+"\nelem1: " + str(elem1))
```

Comment: Justo acabo de notar eso, pero sin tu corrección no hubiese entendido bien como solucionarlo... Te lo agradezco mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar "in", ejemplo `elemento in lista` para buscar un valor en una lista (también en una cadena de caracteres) .. Ejemplos:

```
lista = [
    "hola",
    "bienvenidos",
    666,
    "cadena larga de caracteres"
]

elemento_a_buscar = "hola"

if elemento_a_buscar in lista:
    print("si se encontró => %s " % elemento_a_buscar)
else:
    print("no se encontró >:c ")
```

En un listado de números sería por ejemplo:

```
myList = [1, 5, 6]

a_buscar = 1

if a_buscar in myList:
    print("Se encontró %s en la lista" % a_buscar)
```

Para buscar dentro de una cadena de caracteres puedes usarlo así por ejemplo:

```
if "hola" in "hola cómo estás?":
    print("si se encontró hola en la cadena")
```